# QGIS Python loop integer with select by expression

Tags: pyqgis, loop

I want to use a loop to select values with expression in a layer. The values contain the letters OS and a number (example: "OS1","OS2"). I want to use the loop to increase the number to use my processing script on the features separately. How do I use the selectbyexpression() in the right way to increase the number in a loop?

```
i = 1
OSnumber = str(i)
OSname = 'OS'+OSnumber

OS_trace = Map+'OS_tracés.shp'
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression("attributename = 'Osname'")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following script structure:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

end_number = 5 # OS1, OS2, OS3, OS4, OS5
attribute_name = "attribute_name" # field name containing OS values

for i in range(end_number):
    osname = f"OS{i+1}"
    layer.selectByExpression(f"{attribute_name} = '{osname}'")

    # Do whatever with the selected features
    # For example:
    print(layer.selectedFeatureCount())
```